# How to control programs run at startup?

Tags: kde, startup

I have `wicd`, `hplib` and `psensor` installed. But they all always a run at startup in KDE environment. How can I stop them running at startup?

Comment: Did you check `systemsettings -> startup & shutdown -> autostart ` ? What version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: There's no link for these apps in autostart.

Comment: There is an autostart module in Kubuntu (KDE), I believe the startup applications and programs should be added/removed from startup via the "advanced" tab in that module.  The system settings in Kubuntu should be called KDE control center.

Answer (score 28):

KDE provides a wonderful tool in systemsettings ("Startup and Shutdown" -> "Autostart") for managing your personal autostart services (in either of the .kde directories) however it doesn't cover systemwide autostart scripts provided by your distribution packages, or created by the gnome apps.

Sometimes however it can be useful to override your distribution autostart preferences, for example I don't like having the printer-applet running as I don't own a printer, but it seems a shame to uninstall it in case I need it.

The correct way to disable a package installed is actually to copy it to your personal autostart folder. Anything of the same name in `~/.kde/share/autostart` and/or `/usr/share/autostart/` (also can be `~/.kde4/Autostart`) overrides the .desktop file in the default installations. Once we have copied the .desktop file we can make changes.
Add the following line to the .desktop file you have just copied:

```
Hidden=true
```

KDE also restores your session when you log in, so if `psensor` is running when you log out, it will be started up again when you log in. To change that, just close `psensor` (i.e. actually quit the program, don't just close the window). If `psensor` is not running when you log out, it should not start up again when you log back in.

Comment: Ok, but I am using Kubuntu 15.04 and I cannot get rid of skype autostart at boot since there is not skype app to disable in in Autostart options.  How do I remove skype startup from terminal?

Comment: @MarkoFrelih Did you check in `Skype->Options->General` that `Start Skype Minimised in system tray` is unticked?

Comment: in there is no such option under Linux (at least I cannot find it), since the last version available from Skype's website is 4.3, which is veryy old.

Comment: Can't find .desktop file...  @KernelPanic did you find out how to stop Skype from running at startup?

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe nope sorry.

Comment: I found I had to put the entry into `~/.config/autostart`. Putting it into `~/.kde/Autostart` or `~/.kde/share/autostart` had no effect.

Comment: Since KDE 5.x, this stuff lives in `~/.config/autostart/`. You can also put your own scripts in `~/.config/autostart-scripts/`. See also: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/autostart/

Answer (score 6):

I found this useful, taken from [David Edmundson's blog](http://blog.davidedmundson.co.uk/blog/autostart-in-kde-linux/):

```
~/.kde/Autostart
~/.kde/share/autostart
~/.config/autostart
~/.local/share/autostart
/etc/xdg/autostart
/usr/share/autostart
```

I don't really know why we have so many... Anything inside the `/usr/` or `/etc` folder will have been installed by your distribution.

Answer (score 0):

On */etc/xdg/autostart*
add *.bak* to *.desktop* on filename that you want to stop.

Comment: Did you note this question if over 8 years old. A lot has changed in 8 years. You may want to avoid giving a one line answer with no references to such an old question.