# Kubuntu starts Konsole and Discover every time I on my PC

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5

I have a problem . Every time, I turn on my PC , Kubuntu opens Konsole and Discover. I don't know why it is happening. I don't put my computer to sleep, I shut down it. What is the problem? It's been happening since I installed Kubuntu (yesterday). Please help me.

Comment: Have you checked your startup applications?

Comment: Just to give some link extending further Owen Hines comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/487920/how-to-control-programs-run-at-startup .